# What is λ when two vectors are perpendicular each other against

Tags: vectors, inner-products

The angle between vectors $\vec a$  and $\vec b$ is $120°$ and $|\vec a| = 3|\vec b|$. Define scalar λ so that $\vec a+\vec b$ and $\vec a-λ\vec b$ are perpendicular each other. The answer is $λ = −15$.

So far I have used this approach but don't get the right answer

$$(\vec a+\vec b)\cdot(\vec a-λ\vec b)=0 $$
$$\vec a^2-\vec aλ\vec b + \vec b\cdot\vec a - λ\vec b^2=0 $$
$$ λ= a/b $$

but don't know how to continue from this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If you know the angle, do you know something about their dot product?

Comment: The dot product follows the distributive law. Expand the first line. What do you get?

Comment: @insipidintegrator I think I used distributive law but don't know what do next because of the vectors

Comment: Now, you should use $\vec a\cdot \vec b= \vec b\cdot \vec a=|\vec a||\vec b|\cos\theta$ and $\vec a^2=|\vec a|^2$, $\vec b^2=|\vec b|^2$. Replace $|\vec a|$ with $3|\vec b|$. If you still need any help, feel free to reply. They are vectors, not scalars, so you cannot divide a/b. So the last line is wrong.

Comment: Clues I got from my teacher were to use dot product and then open the components but I don't think I'm using those correctly.  I was wondering can I solve the magnitude of vectors a and b? @insipidintegrator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\vec a\cdot\vec a-\lambda\vec a\cdot\vec b+\vec a\cdot \vec b-\lambda\vec b\cdot\vec b=0$$ Thus $$|\vec a|^2+(1-\lambda)|\vec a||\vec b|\cos120^{\circ}-\lambda|\vec b|^2=0$$ Now put $|\vec a|=3|\vec b|$
$$9|\vec b|^2+3(1-\lambda) |\vec b|^2\left(-\frac12\right)-\lambda |\vec b|^2=0$$ If $|\vec b|≠0$, then $$9+3(1-\lambda) \left(-\frac12\right)-\lambda=0$$ from which $\lambda=-15$.

Comment: Oh I see were I went wrong, thank you so much!